# AttributeError: 'Lines_LineSeries_LineIterator_DataAccessor_Strateg' object has no attribute 'signal_add'

Tags: object, plot, attributes, attributeerror, backtrader

hi i have a big problem please help me the error is Attributes Error lines
i have alredy use ( 'matplotlib.use'("Qt5Agg")) but nothin

!pip install matplotlib==3.2.2
!pip install backtrader
!pip install yfinance

```
from datetime  import datetime
import backtrader as bt
import backtrader.analyzers as btanalyzers
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from backtrader.indicators import CrossOver
class SmaCross(bt.Strategy):

def __init__(self):
    sma1 = bt.ind.SMA(period=21)  
    sma2 = bt.ind.SMA(period=40)  
    self.crossover = bt.ind.CrossOver(sma1, sma2)  
    self.signal_add(bt.SIGNAL_LONG, CrossOver)


cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname=yf.download('MSFT'),
                                fromdate=datetime(2010, 1, 1),
                                todate=datetime(2021, 1, 1)

)

cerebro.adddata(data)
cerebro.addstrategy(SmaCross)
cerebro.run()  
cerebro.plot()
```